# Mouse move automation in windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, mouse

I have created a Windows Service,
In the On start method, i am invoking a Listener for an input device

```
public class LeapMouseServiceService : ServiceBase
{
    private Controller cnt;
    private LeapListener ls;
    public LeapMouseServiceService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {            
        this.cnt.AddListener(ls);
    }
```

MouseOpera has mouse_event from USer32.dll

```
    class MouseOpera
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x01;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

    public static void DeltaMove(int x, int y)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, 0);
    }
```

LeapListener Class has Onframe method

```
class LeapListener : Listener
{
    private Object thisLock = new Object();
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"K:\logs\log.txt",true);
    private void SafeWriteLine(String line)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {                
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    public override void OnInit(Controller controller)
    {
        SafeWriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        SafeWriteLine("Initialized");
    }

    public override void OnConnect(Controller controller)
    {
        SafeWriteLine("Connected");
    }

    public override void OnDisconnect(Controller controller)
    {
        //Note: not dispatched when running in a debugger.
        SafeWriteLine("Disconnected");
    }

    public override void OnExit(Controller controller)
    {
        SafeWriteLine("Exited");
    }

    public override void OnFrame(Controller controller)
    {
        // Get the most recent frame and report some basic information
        Frame frame = controller.Frame();
        MouseOpera.DeltaMove((int)(hand.Direction.Yaw*10),-(int)(hand.Direction.Pitch*10));
```

The log.txt is perfectly capturing all Leap activities when Service is running. But, the mouse movement is not happening. How to make the mouse move automatically from windows service using C# code?

Comment: A service has no concept of user interface, thus mouse events are pointless to it. See more info here about windows station : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: some services have UI.